# How to create a swig typemap to convert a unordered map of string to std::unique_ptr<Foo>'s to a Python dictionary?

Tags: python, c++, interop, swig, swig-typemap

I have a map type in C++ that I'm wrapping and exposing to Python using swig. The map is of type `std::unordered_map<std::string, std::unique_ptr<Foo>>`, where `Foo` is another one of my objects already exposed to Python with swig. I need help creating a typemap so that this custom map type becomes a Python dictionary on the Python end. The complication of course is the `unique_ptr`.

The code for this example is avialable [here](https://github.com/CiaranWelsh/SwigExample) and is built using cmake (see commands below). You will of course need to replace `-DPython_ROOT_DIR=C:\Miniconda3\envs\py39` with the corresponding location to your own Python and `-DSWIG_EXECUTABLE=D:/swigwin-4.0.2/swig.exe`  with the corresponding location to the swig executable on your system.

```
git clone https://github.com/CiaranWelsh/SwigExample.git
cd SwigExample
mkdir build
cd build
cmake -DPython_ROOT_DIR=C:\Miniconda3\envs\py39 -DSWIG_EXECUTABLE=D:/swigwin-4.0.2/swig.exe -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE="Release" ..
cmake --build . --target swig_example --config Release
```

The C++ library code that will be wrapped with swig is:

```
// src/SwigExample.h
#ifndef SWIGEXAMPLE_SWIGEXAMPLE_H
#define SWIGEXAMPLE_SWIGEXAMPLE_H

#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <memory>

class Foo {
public:
    Foo(int x_)
        : x(x_){}
    int x;
};


class SpecialFooMap{
public:
    SpecialFooMap() = default;

    SpecialFooMap(const std::vector<std::string>& labels, const std::vector<int>& values){
        insertFoos(labels, values);
    }

    void insertFoos(const std::vector<std::string>& labels, const std::vector<int>& values){
        if (labels.size() != values.size())
            throw std::invalid_argument("labels and values are not the same size");
        for (int i=0; i<labels.size(); i++){
            map_[labels[i]] = std::make_unique<Foo>(values[i]);
        }
    }
    std::unordered_map<std::string, std::unique_ptr<Foo>> map_;
};

#endif //SWIGEXAMPLE_SWIGEXAMPLE_H
```

And the swig interface file

```
// SwigExample.i
%module swig_example

%{

#define SWIG_FILE_WITH_INIT
#include "SwigExample.h"

%}

%include "std_string.i"
%include "std_unordered_map.i"
%include "std_vector.i"

%template(StringVector) std::vector<std::string>;
%template(IntVector) std::vector<int>;

%typemap(out) SpecialFooMap* {
    // marker for SpecialFooMap
    $result = PyDict_New();
    if (!$result){
        std::string err = "Could not create dict object";
        PyErr_SetString(PyExc_ValueError, err.c_str());
    }
    for (auto& [fooName, fooUniquePtr]: $1->map_){
        // release ownership from the unique_ptr.
        Foo* fooPtr = fooUniquePtr.release();
        // give it to swig
        PyObject* swigOwnedPtr = SWIG_NewPointerObj(
                SWIG_as_voidptr(fooPtr),
                $descriptor(Foo*),
                /*SWIG_POINTER_NEW |  SWIG_POINTER_NOSHADOW*/
                SWIG_POINTER_NEW |  0
        );
        if (!swigOwnedPtr){
            PyErr_SetString(PyExc_ValueError, "Could not create a swig wrapped RoadRunner object from "
                                        "a std::unique_ptr<RoadRunner>");
        }
        int failed = PyDict_SetItem($result, PyUnicode_FromString(fooName.c_str()), swigOwnedPtr);
        if (failed){
            PyErr_SetString(PyExc_ValueError, "Could not create item in dict");
        }
    }
}

%ignore SpecialFooMap::map_;
%include "SwigExample.h"

%extend Foo {
    %pythoncode %{
        def __str__(self):
            return f"<class '{type(self)}'>"
     %}
}
```

As you can see, my strategy is for every item in the hash map, to release the pointer from the `std::unique_ptr<Foo>` and "give" it to swig.

Running the code:

```
f = swig_example.Foo(3)
print(f) # outputs the expected: <class '<class 'swig_example.Foo'>'>
print(type(f)) # outputs the expected: <class 'swig_example.Foo'>
```

But

```
m = swig_example.SpecialFooMap(["first", "second"], [1, 2])
print(m)
```

Outputs:

```
<swig_example.SpecialFooMap; proxy of {'first': <Swig Object of type 'Foo *' at 0x00000272A12E7C90>, 'second': <Swig Object of type 'Foo *' at 0x00000272A12E7B70>} >
```

and

```
print(type(m))
```

Outputs

```
<class 'swig_example.SpecialFooMap'>
```

What I want is for `type(m)` to be a Python `dict` so that `isinstance(m, dict)` evaluates to true.

Comment: Have you looked at the SWIG generated C / C++ wrapper to check that your typemap is being applied? I've used similar dict creating typemaps for function output arguments successfully, so I suspect the problem is in trying to apply a typemap to a constructor result. (Which sort of makes sense as your constructor will no longer be returning an instance of the class.)

Comment: Yes the type maps are being applied. In fact this is what the line `// marker for SpecialFooMap` is for. The typemap is being applied at two locations: 1) `SWIGINTERN PyObject *_wrap_new_SpecialFooMap__SWIG_1(PyObject *SWIGUNUSEDPARM(self), Py_ssize_t nobjs, PyObject **swig_obj) {` and 2) `SWIGINTERN PyObject *_wrap_new_SpecialFooMap__SWIG_0(PyObject *SWIGUNUSEDPARM(self), Py_ssize_t nobjs, PyObject **SWIGUNUSEDPARM(swig_obj)) {`

Comment: > so I suspect the problem is in trying to apply a typemap to a constructor result. So do you think a static "create" method for the class would work better?

Comment: It's odd that the typemap is being used but the returned value isn't a dict. A static method could return your dict, but it wouldn't be creating an instance of your class, it would be creating a dict.

Comment: Which is in fact, exactly what I want =]